# Is there a difference between putting conditionals inside or outside a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

When building a LINQ query for database access, is putting query conditionals inside the query or outside impact performance?

```
Expression<Func<MyObject, bool>> query;
```

Inside:

```
query = x => includeInactives ? includeInactives : x.IsActive;
```

Outside

```
if (!includeInactives)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.IsActive);
}
```

For the inside example, if includeInactives is true, won't it be evaluated on every record, where as for the outside example it's only evaluated once, then not included in the query?

Comment: I'd suggest you [log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx) the SQL that is produced by both queries, and see if there are any differences.

Comment: I  suppose the second one may be a few milliseconds faster, as it checks only for `IsValid` on every row, whereas the first example checks for `includeInactives` also. However you should definitly use a profiler to measure things, as it´ll show you if those milliseconds are really worth the afford or if you have far more performance-breaking issues. Having said this you shouldn´t strife for performance, but for working code, that is easy to understand and thus easy to maintain.

Comment: If the table is huge you might notice a few milliseconds difference because the `bool` **might be** evaluated(compare the generated sql) for every record even if it's a value that is not related to the record and won't change. So i'd prefer the second "outside" approach.

Comment: The difference here will be very little since the value of `includeInactives` will be baked into the query, so the query will stay constant all the time (but this will still generate a *different* query). In general though, you should avoid relying on too many outside things inside your queries. At worst, it could make your filtering being executed in memory instead of by the database.

Comment: @Poke: _"At worst, it could make your filtering being executed in memory instead of by the database"_ That's not true. No db query will be executed in memory if you don't use  methods that force that(f.e. `ToList`,`ToArray`,`AsEnumerable`,...). What are you thinking of?

Comment: @Tory: i'd prefer `includeInactives ? true : x.IsActive`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Hmm, are you sure? What about when I call a method that cannot be supported by IQueryable? `.Where(x => DoSomeHeavyComputation(x))`. Won’t that produce the unfiltered result by the database which will then be filtered by the .NET consumer?

Comment: @poke: if it's not supported (cannot be translated to sql) the LINQ provider will throw an exception. You have to prepend `AsEnumerable` yourself to make it working. But then you are using `Linq-To-Objects` and indeed execute it in memory.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The behavior varies by query provider.  EF will throw an exception, some others do other things, including evaluating the operation in memory.

Comment: @Servy: you know a LINQ provider which can't translate an expression and start to use linq-to-objects by themselves?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, I do.  I consider the behavior highly unfortunate, but I have used a query provider that does exactly that.

Comment: Would the number of conditionals cause any kind of differentiation between the two? From discussion so far is sounds like it would not.

Comment: @TimSchmelter & Servy Interesting, I learned something. Thanks! (Guess that shows how little I use EF to build queries)

Comment: @Servy: i can't think of a use case where this is not a bug. If the provider (silently) evaluates something in memory, he will evaluate the whole query in memory, not only this calculation. And he has to do that with every record  in case of `.Where(x => DoSomeHeavyComputation(x))`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Well, not the whole query, necessarily.  Just that one operation and anything dependant on that operation, which would only be the whole thing if all subsequent operations were dependant on that one operation's result.  It's not a bug given that it's demonstrably intentional (it's not even easy to do; you need to go pretty far out of your way to do it), but as I said before, I consider it bad behavior that I wish it *didn't* do.  Forcing an explicit call in order to evaluate subsequent operations in memory is certainly preferable.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It's called client evaluation and is integral part (and default behavior) of EF Core (the "future of EF") query translator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be no difference in performance, so you should use whatever form you find more readable for you and your development team.

Since the expression from your "Inside" example is evaluated at run time before submitting the expression to RDBMS for evaluation, one of two things is going to happen:

1. `includeInactives` would be `false`, and query would be `x => x.IsActive`, or
2. `includeInactives` would be `true`, and query would be `x => true`

The first case is equivalent to your "Outside" query; the second case would be optimized out by any modern RDBMS.